# Firebase FIRClearcutLogger crash

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-analytics

I am using Firebase analytics in one of our apps - the `FirebaseCore` and `RemoteConfig frameworks`.

This is the crash Report:

```
Fatal Exception: NSRangeException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x1922161c0 __exceptionPreprocess
1     libobjc.A.dylib                0x190c5055c objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x192206f5c -[__NSArrayM removeObjectsInRange:]
3  AppName                       0x100155248 -[FIRClearcutLogger nextPendingRequest]
4  AppName                       0x1001554dc -[FIRClearcutLogger sendNextPendingRequestWithCompletionHandler:]
5  AppName                       0x10015595c __65-[FIRClearcutLogger sendNextPendingRequestWithCompletionHandler:]_block_invoke
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x1910a1200 _dispatch_call_block_and_release
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x1910a11c0 _dispatch_client_callout
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x1910b1558 _dispatch_root_queue_drain
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x1910b10ec _dispatch_worker_thread3
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1912aa2b8 _pthread_wqthread
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1912a9da4 start_wqthread
```

The underlying Exception:

`-[__NSArrayM removeObjectsInRange:]: range {7, 1} extends beyond bounds [0 .. 6]`

`FIRClearcutLogger` is used internally, so I have no real control over it. Moreover, this will be hard to reproduce.

Can this be due to a Race?

Is this issue known, and is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: Thanks for reporting. Would you mind sharing the SDK version of FirebaseCore and if possible, the iOS versions on which the bug happened?

Comment: `Firebase SDK` is 3.9.0, `FirebaseCore` is 3.4.4, `RemoteConfig` is 1.3.1. It happened on iPhone 6, iOS 10.1.1. Thanks.

Comment: This is fixed internally and should make its way out in a release soon.

Comment: @MorganChen thanks for the info. Sounds like an answer to me - do you have a link to track this issue?

Comment: Don't have a link to track, but this fix is going out in the next Firebase release in a few days.